# convert String to Array word by word in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have some text like:

```
DESC:manner How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?
ENTY:cremat What films featured the character Popeye Doyle ?
DESC:manner How can I find a list of celebrities ' real names ?
```

I read them line by line and I want to convert each line to a `string Array` word by word .
like this:

> Array = [DESC, :, manner, How, did, serfdom ,develop, in ,and ,then ,leave, Russia ,?]

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far, and explain what is not working as you expect?

Comment: use `String#split(" ")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want to keep some delimiters and not others (keep `:` and loose the spaces). I think you need a regular expresion to accomplish this. Something like this should do it:

```
String str = "DESC:manner How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?";
String arr[] = str.split("((?<=:)|(?=:))|( )");
```

This uses the Lookahead and Lookbehind RegEx to find/keep the delimiter `:` while we added in a normal split for the space `( )` to trash those.

After this arr should be:

```
arr = [DESC, :, manner, How, did, serfdom, develop, in, and, then, leave, Russia, ?]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] arr = str.replaceAll(":"," : ").split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

String value = "";
String[] values = value.split(" ");

This should get you the array by space as a delimiter.

Comment: i) Let the OP try ii) This doesn't meet the requirements of OP. There's no space between 'DESC',':' and 'manner'.

Comment: It could be only the starter, he has to do the rest.  Meaning, we can guide, no need to code for his requirement.  Agree?

Answer (score 0):

For a more comprehensive solution, you can use boundary matchers, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

```
String s = "DESC:manner How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?";

String[] split = s.split("\\b");
```

the split array contains what you are looking for.

Comment: This would treat the spaces between words as separate strings.

Answer (score 0):

u mean u want to split your string line to a string array.

there are two convenient ways to do this.

first of course is the split method. U can refer this method in the j2se String class.

second would be the regex pattern. U can refer the information in the j2se regex class either

Answer (score 0):

For your example:

```
String[] part = line.split(":| ");
```

Where `line` would be one your example lines.

Note that there is a `space` after the `|` in the regex.

I would advise reading up on Regular Expressions and getting hold of a tool like Expresso to try them out.

Expresso: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: That's not what the OP wanted, it trashes the `:` instead of adding it as an element in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind punctuation being removed from the result, `String#split("\\W")` (split on nonword characters) will do it:

```
// you've got this from the input parser
String inputLine = "DESC:manner How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?";

String[] wordArray = inputLine.split("\\W");
```

That gives:

```
wordArray = [DESC, manner, How, did, serfdom, develop, in, and, then, leave, Russia]
```

If you need punctuation, I don't think a regex will be able to do it, since it does the split by destroying the matched character.

Comment: `I don't think a regex will be able to do it` - sure it can, you just need the corerct regex :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Guava's Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

```
Iterable<String> wordsIterable = Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("\\b")).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(string);
String[] words = Iterables.toArray(wordsIterable, String.class);
```